# Preload a remote image with a callback and timeout option

Tags: jquery

I have an Instagram image (a thumbnail) where, when you click on it, it will load the full size image and it expands from the thumbnail position.

I use the code below at the moment and it works, but I need to have a timeout as well so if it does not load, I move on with the auto playing nature of my website.

```
var image = $("<img />").attr("src", imageUrl + "?" + new Date().getTime());
$(image).load(function(){
    // Expanding image code here
}
```

As far as I have tried I can't use a normal ajax call as I am calling a url from another website and JSONP wont work either.

Any ideas how I can get this to work?

Comment: Could you use an [`error` listener](http://api.jquery.com/error/) to detect load failures? Or are you genuinely worried about the server stalling out and not sending any response at all (or sending a response so slowly that the `load` event might eventually fire but not for a long time)?

Comment: Basically my website is a grid of images, you have the choice to put it in auto mode, I need to do this to keep things moving, maybe the server does not respond or any other reason. The auto play feature cannot stop running though.

Comment: The main problem with it is that I can just move on in the auto playing and remove the loading spinner etc for the un-loaded image, but I need a way to cancel that load.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `setTimeout` and `load` events race. Whichever one fires first cancels the other: the `load` listener is cancelled with [`.off("load")`](http://api.jquery.com/off/), and the timeout is cancelled with [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.clearTimeout):

```
var image = $("<img />").attr("src", imageUrl + "?" + new Date().getTime());

var myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
    // failure behavior

    // we consider load a failure; remove the listener
    $(image).off("load");
}, 10000);

$(image).on("load", function(){
    // Expanding image code here

    // we've succeeded, remove the failure timeout
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for this written by Desandro, it might be useful to you: 
https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

It allows you to specify different events for broken images.  Of course this depends on if you want to wait for the image to load or just mark it as broken if it doesn't load in X seconds.